# Returning Native Objects Using Javascriptcore Glib API

Tags: c, webkit, glib, javascriptcore, webkitgtk

I am learning webExtensions and I had written a sample  web extension for webkit where I used javascriptcore DOM/C API.. I had referred  [Binding native objects with JavascriptCore C Api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47103252/binding-native-objects-with-javascriptcore-c-api) and https://github.com/vrruiz/WebKit-JavaScriptCore-Extensions And I was able to return all data types including native objects.

With recent webkit releases, new JavascriptCore Glib API have been introduced and I am trying to migrate my test code to new JSC glib API. I referred Test code in webkit Tools directory and was able to return native number, string, boolean values to javascript (Using a HTML test app) But I was not able to return any native objects. For example when I tried to return Gfile object , I got below error

> TypeError: unsupported type GObject

I tried changing the return type from G_TYPE_OBJECT to JSC_TYPE_VALUE
But I was not sure how to convert GFile object into JSCvalue. If i don't convert then in app I get NULL object.

HTML & JavaScript code

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Extending JavaScript with WebKit</h1>
  <div id="test-extension"></div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    var display = function () {
        var div = document.getElementById("test-extension");
        var testExt = getTestExtObject('.');
        var extString = "Test Extension Object " +  testExt + "<br>";
        div.innerHTML = extString;
    }
    display();
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

C++ code

```
extern "C" void webkit_web_extension_initialize_with_user_data(WebKitWebExtension* extension, GVariant* userData)
{
    g_signal_connect(webkit_script_world_get_default(), "window-object-cleared", G_CALLBACK(windowObjectCleared), nullptr);
}

static GFile* getTestExtObject(const char* path)
{
    GFile* ret =  g_file_new_for_path(path);
    return ret;
}

static void windowObjectCleared(WebKitScriptWorld* world, WebKitWebPage* page, WebKitFrame* frame, gpointer)
{
    GRefPtr<JSCContext> jsContext = adoptGRef(webkit_frame_get_js_context_for_script_world(frame, world));
    g_assert_true(JSC_IS_CONTEXT(jsContext.get()));
    GRefPtr<JSCValue> function = adoptGRef(jsc_value_new_function(jsContext.get(), "getTestExtObject", G_CALLBACK(getTestExtObject), NULL, NULL, G_TYPE_OBJECT, 1, G_TYPE_STRING));
    jsc_context_set_value(jsContext.get(), "getTestExtObject", function.get());
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I Found answer in WPE Webkit community : https://lists.webkit.org/pipermail/webkit-wpe/2019-June/000183.html

We need to register the class so that JSC can create and handle
wrapped GFiles.

I wrote Sample code just for reference. Which can be found below

https://github.com/munezbn/sample_webkit_extension